# java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation Exception

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

Please find my below query,

```
select nvl(max(transaction_id),0) as  transaction_id from exception_details;
```

If I execute the above query through my jdbc code, it is giving me `java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation` 
my JDBC code is as follows:

```
public int fetchColumnVal(String query) throws SQLException, IllegalAccessException, 
    InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException {

    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        con = getConnection(true);
        pstmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        rs.next();
        int count=rs.getInt(1);
        return count;
    } finally {
        if (isBatchMode) {
            this.cleanResources(null, pstmt);
        }
        else {
            this.cleanResources(con, pstmt);
        }
    }
}
```

and the data type for the column transaction_id in the table is NUMBER

Comment: Try using getBigDecimal or getLong instead of getInt.

Comment: I tried using getBigDecimal() its still giving me the same error and the output of the query is 0 so should i still try using getLong()

Comment: Could you please post the complete error trace?

Comment: The error suggests you're selecting a `varchar2`; can you double-check that the `transaction_id` is actually defined as `number` (I know you already said that, but still...), and that this is actually the query that's causing the error? Can you at least log/display the value of `query` before you execute it to verify what you're running? (It can't be *exactly* that anyway - the trailing semicolon would cause an error).

Answer (score 3):

if you use @Enumerated without define EnumType.STRING, i.e
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
and your table already contain String data (Varchar), you shall get this error, cos.
default EnumType is ORDINAL, i.e EnumType.ORDINAL.

Answer (score 0):

SQL      JDBC/Java                     setXXX             getXXX

NUMERIC    java.math.BigDecimal        setBigDecimal         getBigDecimal

change rs.getInt(1);  to rs.getBigDecimal(1);

(or) type cast number to integer in sql like below for oracle:

CAST(id AS integer)

Comment: Hi, as per your above solution i tried implementing the same in my code as BigDecimal count=rs.getBigDecimal(1); but it is still giving me the same exception

Comment: Can you type cast the column in select query to integer and leave the code rs.getInt(1); and try

Comment: Can you check the syntax of the nvl function, please refer below link for oracle :http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/nvl.php   select cast(nvl(max(transaction_id),0) as integer) as  transaction_id from exception_details;  [also check the 1-st parameter of nvl function it expects string]

Answer (score 0):

I would like to suggest a more traditional approach for ResultSet count checking.
Initially I tried using:

```
       while (RS.next()) {
            RScount = RS.getInt(1);
            Set.add(RS.getString(1));
        }
```

But as my SQL result-set was String, Java kept on throwing:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation
```

Then I changed my code to to plain Vanilla:
Declaration, initialized at 0:

```
Integer RScount = 0; //SQL result set counter
```

And counter code as:

```
    while (RS.next()) {
        RScount++;
        Set.add(RS.getString(1));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting error like

**Exception Foundjava.sql.SQLException: Fail to convert to internal representation.**

I have written my code as :

```
 while(res.next())  
        System.out.println(  res.getInt(1) + "  "
                           + res.getString(2) + "  "
                           + res.getString(3) + "  "
                           + res.getString(4));
```

but my datatype of 1st field in DB was of varchar type.

Then I changed my code to:

```
while(res.next())  
        System.out.println(  res.getString(1) + "  "
                           + res.getString(2) + "  "
                           + res.getString(3) + "  "
                           + res.getString(4));
```

then I got all my data.